# What are the benefits of Entity Classes for Databases?

Tags: language-design, entity, databaselink, databases

To me, using the older database functionality is much simpler:

```
<< DatabaseLink`;
conn = OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["mysql", "ensembldb.ensembl.org"], 
   "Username" -> "anonymous", "Password" -> "", "Catalog" -> "homo_sapiens_core_95_38"];
AbsoluteTiming @ SQLExecute[conn, 
  "SELECT biotype, COUNT(biotype) FROM gene GROUP BY biotype ORDER BY 2 DESC LIMIT 10;"]

Out[]= {0.154305, {{"protein_coding", 
   22686}, {"processed_pseudogene", 10821}, {"lincRNA", 
   8003}, {"antisense", 5824}, {"unprocessed_pseudogene", 
   3373}, {"misc_RNA", 2398}, {"snRNA", 2069}, {"miRNA", 
   1911}, {"TEC", 1098}, {"transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene", 
   1050}}}
```

Than this newer syntax:

```
schema = 
  RelationalDatabase[{"xref", "gene"}, 
   "mysql://anonymous@ensembldb.ensembl.org/homo_sapiens_core_95_38"];
store = EntityStore[schema];
EntityRegister@store;
a = AggregatedEntityClass["gene", 
   "count" -> EntityFunction[g, Length[g["gene_id"]]], "biotype"];
s = SortedEntityClass[a, "count" -> "Descending", 10];
AbsoluteTiming[data = EntityValue[s, {"biotype", "count"}]]

Out[]= {0.507906, {{"protein_coding", 
   22686}, {"processed_pseudogene", 10821}, {"lincRNA", 
   8003}, {"antisense", 5824}, {"unprocessed_pseudogene", 
   3373}, {"misc_RNA", 2398}, {"snRNA", 2069}, {"miRNA", 
   1911}, {"TEC", 1098}, {"transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene", 
   1050}}}
```

They both yield the same thing, and the first method is faster, so what gives? Why was this developed and touted as a big improvement in 12?

**What would have been a better design?** If WRI had added a way of treating SQL sources as out-of-core `Datasets` and thus allowed normal usage of operators and `Query` to work with them.

Comment: There was a discussion about `Entity` functionality at the last WTC - several registered their concerns. I've also raised some issues with WRI. Development seems to be driven more by needs and trades off WL's orthogonality to achieve it.  For example, why is there an `SortedEntityClass` when sorting is just a state? There's no `[[SortedList]]` or `[[SortedAssociation]]`. Doesn't seem like a clean design, though I've not used it. Seems to me if one wanted all this type clutter one could use Python.

Comment: Presumably the "better design" can be built off the latter. I think there's power to not having to directly embed a SQL query as then you can meta-program with it. On the other hand you probably won't be able to beat hard-coded SQL queries. Feels like the difference between high level and low level to me.

Comment: some of the examples and benefits are discussed here https://youtu.be/IWbEHRFuZxg

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Preamble

As was already hinted in the comments, the new functionality is a much higher level. It is basically a compiler from entity query language to SQL, specialized to a given SQL dialect of the underlying database engine.

You can view the new functionality more or less as ORM for WL. It brings similar benefits as e.g. Django ORM brings to python web development. However, in our case, we were able to keep the full set of underlying SQL primitives exposed in some way, so if one wants, one can code almost exactly the thing one would obtain by writing raw SQL. In other words, our system contains both high-level and lower-level primitives.

### Distinctive features of the new relational database functionality

Here are some key features that in our view as developers, make this valuable.

- This can be used by people who know WL but don't know SQL and don't have the desire or time to learn it. This is somewhat similar to the role `Compile` plays for WL / C language pair.
- Query representation is fully symbolic, which allows one to programmatically compose them, and very easily build custom query builders for their own problem / domain, automating construction of the common query parts
- The queries are strongly typed, so a wide range of errors and mistakes will be caught by the compiler at query-building time (rather than at the database level at query run-time), and meaningful diagnostic messages are issued to hint at the cause of the error.
- In cases when a given database backend has semantics for certain operations that is different from WL semantics for the same operations, the compiler makes sure that the WL semantics is preserved on a given db backend, by generating appropriate SQL code.
- The type of composition and nesting for entity queries is functional composition typical for WL, which is very different from the SQL expression composition. One can keep thinking functionally when constructing the queries, whereas SQL requires a different way of thinking that may be unfamiliar to many (related to my first point).
- It is possible to do meaningful work with individual entities. This is useful on a number of levels, from better understanding of the data to quick prototyping and also debugging of complex queries.
- Transparent treatment of subqueries, including correlated subqueries - which get translated into nested `EntityFunction` constructs.
- There are certain primitives such as relations, which are very powerful and allow concise queries built in a natural way, which would save the time and mental overhead even for people well-familiar with SQL.

### Some examples

Let's consider a few examples to back the points I just made. Some of the examples here are borrowed from the tutorial, which will be very soon added to the official documentation and has been also written by the author of this post.

#### Initialization

Titanic dataset:

```
titanicDB = RelationalDatabase[URLDownload[CloudObject[
"https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/documentation/titanic.sqlite"
]]];
Quiet @ EntityRegister @ EntityStore @ titanicDB

(* {"titanic"} *)
```

[Classic models](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sample-database.aspx) database:

```
rdb = RelationalDatabase[FindFile["ExampleData/ecommerce-database.sqlite"]];
EntityRegister[EntityStore[rdb]]

(* 
   {"productlines", "payments", "offices", "products", 
    "customers", "employees", "orderdetails", "orders"}
*)
```

#### The query syntax and building on familiarity with WL

Consider the titanic dataset. Here is a simple query that selects all surviving passengers in first class with age <= 15:

```
EntityValue[
  FilteredEntityClass[
    "titanic", 
    EntityFunction[
      p, 
      p["class"] == "1st" && p["age"] <= 15 && p["survived"] == 1
    ]
  ],
  {"class", "age", "sex", "survived"},
  "PropertyAssociation"
]

(* 
   {
     <|"class" -> "1st", "age" -> 1, "sex" -> "male", "survived" -> 1|>, 
     <|"class" -> "1st", "age" -> 11, "sex" -> "male","survived" -> 1|>, 
     <|"class" -> "1st", "age" -> 14, "sex" -> "female", "survived" -> 1|>, 
     <|"class" -> "1st", "age" -> 4, "sex" -> "male", "survived" -> 1|>, 
     <|"class" -> "1st", "age" -> 15, "sex" -> "female", "survived" -> 1|>, 
     <|"class" -> "1st", "age" -> 13, "sex" -> "male", "survived" -> 1|>, 
     <|"class" -> "1st", "age" -> 6, "sex" -> "male", "survived" -> 1|>
   }
*)
```

and in this case, the SQL query is pretty simple too:

```
SELECT class, age, sex, survived 
FROM titanic 
WHERE class = '1st' AND age <= 15 AND survived = 1
```

But for those who are not familiar with SQL, the WL query should be very easy to understand, since it follows very closely what one would've done in WL:

```
KeyTake[
  Select[
    EntityValue["titanic", {"class", "age", "sex", "survived"}, "PropertyAssociation"],
    Function[
      p, 
      p["class"] == "1st" && p["age"] <= 15 && p["survived"] == 1
    ]
  ],
  {"class", "age", "sex", "survived"}
]
```

where `EntityValue` call is only used to provide initial data to WL, loading in the entire table.

Here is a more complex example: split all passengers into age classes 0-20, 20-40, 40-60, 60-80, etc. years old, and compute the fraction of surviving passengers for each passenger class, age group and sex, then sort the results by that fraction in descending order.

Here is the WL query that does it:

```
EntityValue[
  SortedEntityClass[
    AggregatedEntityClass[
      ExtendedEntityClass[
        "titanic",
        "ageGroup" -> EntityFunction[t, Ceiling[t["age"] / 20]]
      ], 
      "surviverFraction" -> EntityFunction[t, Mean[t["survived"]]],
      {"class", "ageGroup", "sex"}
    ],
    "surviverFraction" -> "Descending"
  ],
  {"class", "ageGroup", "sex", "surviverFraction" }
] // Short[#, 5] &

(* 
  {
   {1st,Missing[NotAvailable],female,1.}, {3rd,4,female,1.}, 
   {1st,3,female,0.977273},{1st,2,female,0.970149},{2nd,1,female,0.962963},
   <<20>>,{1st,4,male,0.0666667},{3rd,3,male,0.0645161},
   {2nd,3,male,0.0357143},{3rd,4,male,0.}
  }
*)
```

and in this case, the SQL is not that simple any more. I will show the generated SQL, but the hand-written one will not be that different:

```
SELECT "T235".class, "T235"."ageGroup", "T235".sex, "T235"."surviverFraction" 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    "T234"."ageGroup" AS "ageGroup", 
    "T234".class AS class, 
    "T234".sex AS sex, 
    avg("T234".survived) AS "surviverFraction" 
  FROM (
   SELECT 
     CAST(ceil(CAST("titanic_T232".age AS REAL) / CAST(20 AS REAL)) AS INTEGER) AS "ageGroup", 
     "titanic_T232".class AS class, 
     "titanic_T232".sex AS sex, 
     "titanic_T232".survived AS survived 
   FROM titanic AS "titanic_T232"
  ) AS "T234" 
  GROUP BY "T234".class, "T234"."ageGroup", "T234".sex
) AS "T235" 
ORDER BY "T235"."surviverFraction" DESC
```

In this case, I would argue that WL query is way more accessible and clear.

#### Symbolic nature of the WL queries, and query composition

This and other sections will be using the classic models db.

Consider the query that aggregates over the payments and produces total payments for all customers:

```
totalPayments = AggregatedEntityClass[
  "payments",
  "totalPaid" -> EntityFunction[p, Total[p["amount"]]],
  "customerNumber"
]
```

This can be used on its own right, for example to find the five top-paying customers:

```
EntityValue[
  SampledEntityClass[
    SortedEntityClass[
      totalPayments,
      "totalPaid" -> "Descending"
    ],
    5
  ],
  {"customerNumber", "totalPaid"}
]

(* 
  {{141, 715739.}, {124, 584188.}, {114, 180585.}, {151, 177914.}, {148, 156251.}} 
*)
```

However, it can also be used to, for example, get total payments of all customers served by a specific employee:

```
EntityValue[
  AggregatedEntityClass[
    CombinedEntityClass["customers", totalPayments, "customerNumber"],
    "customersTotalForEmployee" -> EntityFunction[c, Total[c["totalPaid"]]],
    "salesRepEmployeeNumber"
  ],
  {"salesRepEmployeeNumber", "customersTotalForEmployee"}
] // Short

(*  {{1165,989907.},{1166,347533.},<<11>>,{1621,457110.},{1702,387477.}} *)
```

So, one can build the queries from pieces, holding those pieces in variables or generating them with function calls. This is pretty powerful.

#### Symbolic query transformations

Programmatic access to queries and their symbolic nature can also be useful for certain more advanced scenarios, such as nontrivial query transformations or generation.

As an example, consider operator forms for common query building blocks. At present, for various reasons there is no direct support for those, for the core Entity framework query building blocks. Yet users often prefer this style of query writing, and it can in some cases make queries more readable by reducing the amount of nesting in the query.

Below is a simple implementation of an alternative syntax that would support operator forms.

```
ClearAll[filter, sample, aggregate, combine, extend, sortby]
$translations = {
   filter -> FilteredEntityClass, 
   sample -> SampledEntityClass, 
   aggregate -> AggregatedEntityClass, 
   combine -> CombinedEntityClass,
   extend -> ExtendedEntityClass, 
   sortby -> SortedEntityClass,
   ev ->  EntityValue
};

entityClassQ[_String?EntityFramework`EntityTypeExistsQ] := True
entityClassQ[ (Alternatives @@ Keys[ $translations])[___]] := True
entityClassQ[_] := False

compileQuery[q_?entityClassQ] := ReplaceAll[q, $translations ]

Scan[
  Function[p, p[args___][c_?entityClassQ] := p[c, args]],
  Keys[ $translations]
]
```

The following example query is written in operator style and does the following: selects the five top-paying customers and returns their customer number, customer name and total amount they have paid, sorted in the order of decreasing total amount:

```
compileQuery[
  "payments" // RightComposition[
    aggregate[
      "totalPaid" -> EntityFunction[p, Total[p["amount"]]],
      "customerNumber"
    ],
    combine["customers", "customerNumber"],
    sortby["totalPaid" -> "Descending"],
    sample[5],
    ev[{
      "customerName",
      EntityProperty["customers", "customerNumber"], 
      "totalPaid"
    }]
  ]
]

(* 
   {
     {"Euro+ Shopping Channel", 141, 715739.}, 
     {"Mini Gifts Distributors Ltd.", 124, 584188.}, 
     {"Australian Collectors, Co.", 114, 180585.}, 
     {"Muscle Machine Inc", 151, 177914.}, 
     {"Dragon Souveniers, Ltd.", 148, 156251.}
   } 
*)
```

which is arguably much closer to so much desired by many `Dataset` queries. I will leave it as an exercise to the adventurous to allow the use of `Function` (including slot-based ones) in such queries in place of `EntityFunction`, as well as to extend this code to support subqueries.

Note how easy it was to create your own DSL / syntactic sugar on top of existing functionality. This wouldn't have been so had the framework not exposed purely symbolic queries. It will be just as easy to build your own custom query builders, specialized to your domain.

#### Subqueries

Subqueries normally are parts of the larger query, which in the WL context can be expressed using EntityValue. On the SQL side, most of the time this corresponds to the inner SELECT statement with a single field, typically returning a scalar (either because there is a single row or because aggregation is being performed), but sometimes also returning a column (to be used in the IN clause, which would correspond to the use of MemberQ on the Entity framework side).

The following example, selecting all products with the MSRP price within the top 10% of most expensive products, in terms of the price range,  represents a simple, uncorrelated subquery:

```
EntityValue[
  FilteredEntityClass[
    "products",
    EntityFunction[
      p,
      p["MSRP"] >= 0.9 * EntityValue["products", "MSRP", Max]
    ]
  ],
  {"productName", "MSRP"}
]

(* 
   {
     {"1952 Alpine Renault 1300", 214.3}, 
     {"2003 Harley-Davidson Eagle Drag Bike", 193.66}, 
     {"1968 Ford Mustang", 194.57}, 
     {"2001 Ferrari Enzo", 207.8}
   }
*)
```

To my mind, this is pretty easy to understand, also for people who are not familiar with SQL.

Correlated subqueries are also supported.

The following more complex version of the previous query extends each product with the number of products that are within a window of $15 from the current product, in terms of MSRP:

```
EntityValue[
  SortedEntityClass[
    ExtendedEntityClass[
      "products",
      "closelyPricedProductsCount" -> EntityFunction[
        p,
        EntityValue[
          FilteredEntityClass[
            "products",
            EntityFunction[pr, Abs[pr["MSRP"] - p["MSRP"]] <= 15]
          ],
          "productCode",
          Length
        ]
      ]
    ],
    {"closelyPricedProductsCount" -> "Descending", "MSRP" -> "Descending"}
  ],
  {"productName", "MSRP", "closelyPricedProductsCount"}
] // Short

(* {{1949 Jaguar XK 120,90.87,33},<<108>>,{1952 Alpine Renault 1300,214.3,2}} *)
```

Where the subquery inside `EntityFunction` that defines the `"closelyPricedProductsCount"` extended property is a correlated subquery, since the filtering of products now depends on the price of the current product, which has to be referenced from that filtering/aggregation subquery.

#### Relations and single entities

Relations provide a high-level way to perform lookups for properties in entity classes/types related to a given one (related database tables), without performing explicit joins. Their internal implementation can utilize different tools to achieve this goal, such as subqueries and/or joins, but these are hidden from the user.

Relations are entity-valued and entity-class-valued entity properties, generated by the Entity framework for related entity types (database tables). In addition to the properties that correspond to existing table columns, new properties are created by the Entity framework for tables that are related to other tables. They constitute the mechanism to provide a higher-level (w.r.t. explicit joins or subqueries) way to use data from multiple related entity types (database tables) in queries.

Consider properties for type "employees":

```
EntityProperties["employees"]

(*
 {
  EntityProperty["employees", "employeeNumber"], 
  EntityProperty["employees", "lastName"], 
  EntityProperty["employees", "firstName"], 
  EntityProperty["employees", "extension"], 
  EntityProperty["employees", "email"], 
  EntityProperty["employees", "officeCode"], 
  EntityProperty["employees", "reportsTo"], 
  EntityProperty["employees", "jobTitle"], 
  EntityProperty["employees", "employees-reportsTo"], 
  EntityProperty["employees", "employees-reverse"], 
  EntityProperty["employees", "offices"], 
  EntityProperty["employees", "customers"]
}
*)
```

There are four properties that do not correspond to existing database columns in this example: `"offices"`, `"customers"`, `"employees-reportsTo"` and `"employees-reverse"`.

One of the simplest ways to understand relations is in the context of single entities.

For a simple example, consider some particular employee:

```
emp = Part[EntityList["employees"], 10]

(* Entity["employees", 1216] *)
```

The properties in question correspond respectively to customers served by this employee, office for which this employee works, the manager of this employee and all employees for whom this employee is the manager:

```
emp[EntityProperty["employees", "customers"]]
emp[EntityProperty["employees", "offices"]]
emp[EntityProperty["employees", "employees-reportsTo"]]
emp[EntityProperty["employees", "employees-reverse"]]

(*
  EntityClass["customers", {"salesRepEmployeeNumber" -> 1216}]

  Entity["offices", "2"]

  Entity["employees", 1143]

  EntityClass["employees", {"reportsTo" -> 1216}]
*)
```

Relations can be entity valued or entity-class valued.

The following query finds an entity class of all coworkers for the given employee:

```
emp[EntityProperty["employees", "offices"]]["employees"]

(* EntityClass["employees", {"officeCode" -> "2"}] *)
```

The following is a more interesting query that returns all employees who work in the same office and report to the same manager as the given employee:

```
EntityList @ FilteredEntityClass[
  emp[EntityProperty["employees", "offices"]]["employees"],
  EntityFunction[e, e["reportsTo"] == emp["reportsTo"]]
]

(* {Entity["employees", 1188], Entity["employees", 1216]} *)
```

One can use relations to economically formulate queries. Here is how one can use relations to compute the number of employees for each office:

```
EntityValue[
  "offices",
  {
    "officeCode", 
    EntityFunction[o, EntityValue[o["employees"], "employeeNumber", Length]]
  }
]

(* {{"1", 6}, {"2", 2}, {"3", 2}, {"4", 5}, {"5", 2}, {"6", 4}, {"7", 2}} *)
```

Note that relations allow one to use data from different related tables, while staying on a higher level of abstraction w.r.t. explicit joins or subqueries.

For a more involved example, consider the following query that computes, for each office, the maximal number of customers that a single employee in that office deals with.

This is how it can be written using relations:

```
EntityValue[
  ExtendedEntityClass[
    "offices",
    "maxEmployeeCustomerCount" -> EntityFunction[
      o,
      EntityValue[
        ExtendedEntityClass[
          o["employees"],
          "customerCount" -> EntityFunction[
            e,
            EntityValue[e["customers"], "customerNumber", Length]
          ]
        ],
        "customerCount",
        Max
      ]
    ]
  ],
  {"officeCode", "maxEmployeeCustomerCount"}
]

(* {{"1", 6}, {"2", 6}, {"3", 8}, {"4", 10}, {"5", 5}, {"6", 5}, {"7", 9}} *)
```

The logic here is pretty transparent: we start with the offices, and for each one we compute the maximal number of customers served by any employee in that office, just as requested. To do that, we add the new `"customerCount"` property to all employees in a given office. For the office bound to `o`, the entity class of all employees in that office is given by the relation `o["employees"]`. Since it is an entity class, we can use it anywhere where entity classes are allowed, in the query - in particular, in `ExtendedEntityClass`. For each employee (say, biud to `e` variable), all customers served by that employee, form an entity class given by the relation `e["customers"]`. The two nested `EntityFunction`-s represent correlated subqueries, performing the aggregations.

This may look a bit complex, but this is not an easy query. Those who are familiar with SQL, may try their hand at it, and will likely observe that the resulting SQL will not be as simple to understand as the above WL query.

### Current shortcomings

#### Speed / performance

We did not particularly emphasize the performance in this first version of the project. However, this is something we will definitely work on to improve in the very near future. The current performance differences w.r.t. DatabaseLink will hopefully be removed or may be even turned around soon.

#### Read-only

Currently read-only workflows are supported. Supporting writing to databases is one of the objectives for the next version.

#### SQL support

There are a number of constructs we don't yet support. We hope to be able to extend the support in the future. A lot will depend on the user feedback - if there is a strong support / multiple requests from the users to add extended support for certain SQL features, we are more likely to get the development time allocated for that.

#### Alternative query syntaxes

There have been requests to support `Dataset` syntax, which might make it on our roadmap. One of the design issues here is that `Dataset` allows a much wider set of operations and generally repersents a hierarchical rather than tabular structure. Which means that relational database - backed `Dataset` would have to fail on a wide variety of operations not available for relational databases. A better option would've been to design a special tabular type of `Dataset` with restricted query language, but this will take some work to keep it consistent with the main `Dataset` functionality.

### Summary

I tried to summarize the distinctive features of the new relational database support functionality, which (in our view) make it powerful and attractive to use, particularly for the users who are well familiar with WL, but not so much with SQL.

A lot in the future directions of development of this functionality may depend on how actively the users will try to use it and provide their feedback.

Comment: Nice summary Leonid. Can you share an example of how an SQL window function would be expressed using the entity framework e.g. LAG/LEAD .. OVER .. PARTITION BY .. ORDER BY.. FOLLOWING.

Comment: So SQL-backed Dataset isn't even on the roadmap yet?  It would be so convenient to use the same symbols and Query! Then we could finally really use JoinAcross and friends...

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi Window functions are not supported yet. I will try to push for their support.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin what other major sql features are not yet support?

Comment: @user5601 It is considered for a roadmap. I will get back here with more information when things are more clear.

Comment: @user5601 We currently work on the support of `UNION`, `UNION ALL`, `INTERSECT` and `EXCEPT`. It would also be nice to support `WITH` (but the recusrive version will require some design). Also, we don't yet support / expose cursors which one might iterate on the WL side, which can be a problem for large result sets. The date and time support is incomplete to say the least.  It would be also good to better support relations than we do now, although this is not an SQL feature per se. And of course, the whole thing of writing to a database and changing the schema.

Comment: This is a very important document. Thanks, Leonid for writing it. I particularly appreciate your discussion of how to use the new functionality using operator constructs. Could I STRONGLY urge that something like this post be added to the official documentation. It is too useful and important to be relegated to a Stack Exchange response (not that there's anything wrong with Stack Exchange).

Comment: @SethChandler This discussion is based on a much larger and more detailed tutorial which I wrote and which now undergoes final touches before being added to the official documentation via a paclet update. So I hope we will get there in roughly a one week time from now.

Comment: Nice write-up! However, I don't really agree with you where you write "I will show the generated SQL, but the hand-written one will not be that different". The generated SQL with 3 levels of nested SELECTs is rather convoluted whereas a simple 
SELECT class, CEIL(age/20.) AS AgeGroup, sex, avg(1.0*survived) AS 
surviverFraction
FROM titanic
GROUP BY class, CEIL(age/20.), sex
ORDER BY 4 DESC
would do the trick. To be honest, I feel this is much easier to read (when better formatted than possible in this comment) than the Mathematica expression or the SQL code it generated.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Partly agree, for those who know SQL, their hand-written SQL will probably be simpler and shorter, at least in cases like this one. But, first, this requires familiarity with SQL and the SQL way of thinking, second, hopefully we will have a better optimizer in subsequent versions of the product, which would produce SQL closer to the hand-written one, and third, things like relations will still be more economical than explicit joins etc (but again, our current code generation for relations is suboptimal and has to be improved). But you made a good point, food for thought for us

Comment: Interestingly, 'CEIL' is not an SQLite keyword, and my query doesn't work when executed using pandas/Python or SQLiteStudio, but it works through the driver that Mathematica is using for SQLite (or Mathematica is using a newer version of SQLite that knows about CEIL; but I haven't found anything about this online).

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Some functions have been implemented in python and added to SQLite at connection time. This is one of them. Here are [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.create_function) describing this. Of course, this has certain performance implications. So in a sense, what is currently generated is not always a standalone SQL. I have almost forgot about this point, while it is an imporant one.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries This is currently only used for SQLite. Other functions like this are: `internal_regexp` , `power`, `log`, `floor`, `sin`, `cos`, `tan`, `asin`, `acos`, `atan`, `atan2`, `xor`, `variance`, `stddev`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Ah I see, very interesting to know.

Comment: @SethChandler The tutorial is live now and should get into every existing V12 installation, so you probably just have it already, or will have after a few kernel / frontend restarts. It won't be found by the help search (not in the index), but it is referenced from most relevant  reference pages, such as the one for `RelationalDatabase` (it is named "Relational Databases Quick Start"). Note that it is still not quite complete. I have another one planned, with a greater level of technical detail, but the time frame for it isn't clear yet.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin is this project alive? I haven’t see any news in the WTC2021 or 2020.

Comment: @Murta The project is functioning and maintained within the same scope as initially developed. Unfortunately, there was an executive decision to stop any active development for it, which happened around a year ago. There are some not yet well documented features that we were able to squeeze in (such as e.g. embedded  SQL functionality, that allows one to embed SQL strings inside symbolic queries, bypassing many of the current limitations of the framework, or for example, some support for writing to databases). There is some hope that the project might be revived, but it is not clear.

Comment: @Murta Having written large parts of SQL generator / compiler and some other components of the project, and invested around 3 years into it, I of course can't welcome the present state of affairs for it, but there isn't much I or anyone from the Databases team can do about this situation, other than hope that at some point the work on the project will be considered valuable enough to be resumed. One thing we might be able to do some time soon would be to open-source it, since this has been discussed and green-lighted before - assuming that that decision is not going to change.

Comment: @Murta At least, we do perform regular bug-fixes for Databases, so the project is being maintained.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin thanks for your fast reply. I’m interested in the open source code if this happens.

Comment: @Murta Good to know, I will keep that in mind. The way the framework is designed should make it possible and not too complicated to use some  other (compared to entities) query language as a frontend for SQL compiler we have, for example some variant of Dataset-like query language, and it is easy to build custom query generators on top of entity-level queries as well.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin that's pity :( The SQL backend for Entity framework looked promising and I tried to use it but the first example proved to be too slow (http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/RelationalDatabasesQuickStart.html)

Comment: @PavelPerikov I have some unfinished work to speed it up by about 20 times or so. I hope to get it in soon enough. The most time is currently spent on compiling the SQL query, and my improvement was in the spirit of prepared statements for entities, where the parametrized query is pre-compiled and then is much faster.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin that's great... Pity it's not open source. I very well understand the motivation to keep the stable API but I'm a  bit tired of reverse engineering :) 

Hope your work on this will continue

Comment: @PavelPerikov It has been greenlighted to be open-sourced by our higher-ups. It is only a question when this happens, since this process also requires some effort, and is considered rather low priority at the moment.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin How do you get the generated `SQL` from the `EntityFramework`?

Comment: @user13892 IIRC, and assuming that you have ``Databases` `` / ``EntityFramework` `` loaded / running, you need to set ``Databases`Database`$DBQueryLogger = Echo``, for example. You can use any other function instead of `Echo`, and the generated SQL string will be passed to it. Keep in mind that for some backends, notably SQLite, the generated SQL may include custom SQL functions defined by the framework, which don't exist on a vanilla db backend.