# Querying ( e.g. ) Google Trends Data with Mathematica front-end

Tags: data-acquisition, databaselink, sql

Mathematica has some excellent data query and analysis methods, but can also perform as a front-end to an SQL database.

Having worked as an SQL DBA in the past I would like to investigate further what Mathematica can do, for that purpose I am looking for some ( any ) online avalaible SQL database I can connect to and perform queries on.

I have been told that there are `tons` of online SQL practice databases. My bad is that I wasn't able to find any. From that my thoughts went to Google Trends, although it doesn't seem to have a connection to query front-ends other than it's own. It doesn't have to be a Google Trends database.

Basically any ( relatively large ) database will do.

Can anyone suggest a way to go further with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://learnsql.com/blog/free-online-datasets-to-practice-sql/

Comment: I have been there, thank you Syed. I need an SQL database connection string : user / password / networkaddress:port ; did you find one on this blog ?

Comment: I think that a service (such as querying someone's database) would not come for free except for the most limited usage; but you can download datasets to practice on your own computer. Another good source for data: https://databank.worldbank.org/home

Comment: There is a more modern (than DatabaseLink) framework shipped with Mathematica starting from version 12, which uses entities and EntityFramework as a front end and generates SQL for a specific backend, for you. It is however limited to reading from databases, at least in terms of documented functionality. You can look at [this Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/199340/what-are-the-benefits-of-entity-classes-for-databases) for a shorter description, and [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/RelationalDatabasesQuickStart.html) is a longer, more detailed tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can experiment with the [RNACentral](https://rnacentral.org/help/public-database) public PostgreSQL database.

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"]

conn = OpenSQLConnection[
  JDBC["PostgreSQL", "hh-pgsql-public.ebi.ac.uk/pfmegrnargs"],
  "Username" -> "reader", "Password" -> "NWDMCE5xdipIjRrp"
  ]
```

List of tables

```
tables = SQLTableNames[conn]
```

Columns in the `xref` table

```
SQLColumns[conn, "xref"]
```

Extract just the column names

```
SQLColumns[conn, "xref"] // 
 Cases[#, SQLColumn[{"xref", column_}, ___] :> column] &
```

Execute a query using an SQL string.

```
SQLExecute[conn, "select * from xref where ac = 'OTTHUMT00000106564.1'"]
```

Same query using WL [`SQLSelect`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/DatabaseLink/ref/SQLSelect.html) expression queries

```
SQLSelect[conn, "xref", SQLColumn["ac"] == "OTTHUMT00000106564.1"]
```

Close the connection when you are done

```
CloseSQLConnection[conn]
```